# youtube-ios-player-helper and chromecast

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, chromecast

I'm building a swift3 app that plays Youtube videos using [YTH](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) for ios and I want to know if it supports chromecast, if so, how can I enable it?
If not, what should I use?

Comment: chrome cast and YTH are sepaeate, ,but it is possible we can play yth video  to chrome cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether YTH supports chrome cast or not, but you can always cast content from your app to chromecast. 
All you need is the media url which will be used as content id on receiver app.

So basically, you can follow the standard implementation of chromecast integration. And after that when you are building media information, use your youtube video's url as content id and try casting that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use https url. It won't be able to play. I have the same issue but I saw that the Chromecast only works with http url. So you have to make a local http url and make that allowable from your device.